# Apache Spark Standalone works slowly

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am developer, my app is in java language using Spring boot framework, and I have installed spark master and 5 workers each have 512 Gb RAM and 100 cores, actually my project works, but very slowly. My question is how I should configure my spark in my code? when my app is developing connecting remote spakr(StandAlone) server, my code will be submitted really? full explanation please the whole scenario please!

here is configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class SparkAppConfig {
    @Bean
    public SparkConf sparkConf() {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("SpringSparkDemo")
                .setSparkHome("home")
                .setMaster("spark://localhost:7077")
//                .set("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost/mongo_test.test")
//                .set("spark.mongodb.output.uri","mongodb://localhost/mongo_test.test")
//                .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
                ;
        System.out.println("spark configuration is established");
        return sparkConf;
    }

    @Bean
    public JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext() {
        JavaSparkContext sparkContext=new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf());
       // sparkContext.addFile("file:////home/hsperfdata_spark/");
        return sparkContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SparkSession sparkSession() {

         SparkSession ss=SparkSession
                .builder()
                .sparkContext(javaSparkContext().sc())
                //.config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost/mongo_test.test")
             //   .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri","mongodb://localhost/mongo_test.test")
//                .config("spark.jars","/data/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.4.1.jar")
//                .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")

                .getOrCreate();
        System.out.println("spark session created");
        return ss;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
```

here is read from db

```
Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession
                .read()
                .format("mongodb")
                .option("database", "testdb")
                .option("collection", "balances")
                .load();
        df.printSchema();
        df.show();
```